# KML issues with the altitude of a linear ring when not extruded

Tags: java, swing, kml, google-earth

I'm trying to have 2 sets of linear rings on a google earth.

One I have that is on the ground and flat that just has the color, location. 
extrude =0 and altitude =0 , relative to ground.

The one I want to have an altitude an extrude to the surface.  This is a subset of the other linear ring same location points. 
extrude=1 altitude >0  ,  relative to ground

So basically they should start at ground, one is flat and the other has a height.
But it appears that the one that is not extruded isn't really on the ground and the same amount for every point. I tried clamp to ground and that way underneeath the other linear ring. I've tried using negative altitude and tried using a negative altitude offset but those don't seem to work. So I'm getting frustrated.

Any ideas for me try?, Thank you very much,

Answer (score 1):

If you using LinearRing as the outer boundary of a Polygon then you need to specify the *altitudeMode* in the Polygon element. If you're specifying the LinearRing geometry directly then you must add the *altitudeMode* to the LinearRing element.

Here's a KML example with two LinearRing places: one extruded with height relative to ground and the other flat clamped to ground:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Document>
        <name>ring test</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <Placemark>
            <name>extruded</name>
            <LinearRing>
                <extrude>1</extrude>
                <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
                <coordinates>
              -122.43193945401,37.801983684521,10
              -122.431564131101,37.8020327731402,10
              -122.431499536494,37.801715236748,10
              -122.43187136387,37.8016634915437,10
              -122.43193945401,37.801983684521,10
            </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>ground</name>
            <LinearRing>
               <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                <coordinates>
                -122.4318558244244,37.801933902335
                -122.4315693369527,37.80197196367308
                -122.4315227485117,37.80176063190402
                -122.4318191012996,37.80172146704169
                -122.4318558244244,37.801933902335
            </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

If the shape covers a large area then you may want to set [tessellate=1](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#tessellate) on the ground-based LinearRing so it follows the curvature of the earth.

Comment: Thanks! At first, I didn't think that was working in a mountainous area, but after doing a before/after, I saw it was working well (just that GE had some peaks that would still go over the poly based on tessellation).  Very helpful.